# GParted - Testing for problems after shrinking too close to the data

Tags: linux, ubuntu, partitioning, gparted

I used gparted to shrink a 1TB volume with about 458GB of data to 470GB. I had Ubuntu installed. Apparently it went well at first. I restarted and Ubuntu had problems logging in Unity. It said there's no space left on disk. I deleted some stuff I didn't need and now it boots with some messed up configurations.

Is there a way to make sure that gparted hasn't ruined any of my files?
I now understand I should've left about 10% extra but didn't. Could the partition have needed more free space and deleted my files? Is there any way to check this/what would the deleted files look like? (With size zero maybe?).

BTW, there was no error in GParted.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

It probably depends on a couple things.

First, if you put in "470000000000 bytes" for your new volume size, that's only little more than 458GB, since 1 kB = 1024 bytes... food for thought in your analysis.

Second, what you did with the reset of the space in the volume?  If you already allocated it to something else and started using it, you may have overwritten the beginning of your old files.  I would encourage you to try to RE-extend it with GParted, and see if everything still works, and your files are available - not sure this will work, though.  THEN resize back down to a more appropriate size.

Good luck.